# ngx-google-analytics with cookie consent in angular

Tags: angular, google-analytics, gdprconsentform

I have [ngx-google-analytics](https://github.com/maxandriani/ngx-google-analytics) built into my website and it works very well so far. Problem: I live in the EU and now I need a cookie consent banner that should be able to turn tracking with ngx-google-analytics on or off.
Can you somehow load modules dynamically? Or is there another way to activate the plugin only after consent?

Comment: The [google analytics docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out#opt-out_of_measurement_for_your_site) mentions a global window property that can be set to disable analytics. You could set it to disable when your app loads and enable it when the user confirms.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Unfortunately window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true; does not stop the connection to the google servers or maybe I am doing something wrong. But I think it is important for GDPR compliance that no connection to google is established.

Answer (score 1):

The library is using [`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) token, which loads at start up time, before anything else in your Angular application. You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/maxandriani/ngx-google-analytics/blob/2dc6bab54ef0a2104e39977e9385291427edf60f/projects/ngx-google-analytics/src/lib/initializers/google-analytics.initializer.ts#L12). Scroll down near the bottom, you will see it appends the google-tag-script into the DOM.

And [here](https://github.com/maxandriani/ngx-google-analytics/blob/2dc6bab54ef0a2104e39977e9385291427edf60f/projects/ngx-google-analytics/src/lib/services/google-analytics.service.ts#L43) is where it uses `gtag` to send data to the server

I don't know much about GTM, but as in your description, I can make an assumption that the solution should be either do not let the library load at all or to stop it from sending data to server.

- Because of APP_INITIALIZER token, it cannot wait until users click OK in the cookie consent banner
- Because there's no if/else, meaning no condition you can put to stop it from sending data to server once it loaded.
- You said it yourself, this option `window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true;`  won't work.

Conclusion: unfortunately, with this current library, you cannot achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you that you took the time to look into it. I will try to do it without the library.